# Strange char**/calloc behavior

Tags: c++

When I debug the following code, `strncpy` works fine but as soon as the loop exits, I see that `parent_var_names` is pointing `NULL/0xfdfdfddf`. I am puzzled!

```
parent_var_names = (const char**)calloc(net->nodes[x]->num_parents, sizeof(const char*));
for(int i(1); i < net->nodes[x]->num_parents; ++i)
{
  parent_var_names[i] = (const char*)malloc(strlen(rhs_arr[net->nodes[x]->markov_parents[i]]));
  strncpy((char*)parent_var_names[i], (char*)rhs_arr[net->nodes[x]->markov_parents[i]], strlen(rhs_arr[net->nodes[x]->markov_parents[i]]));
}
```

Comment: C or C++? Pick one. And it better not be C++.

Comment: well yea. its a c++ compiler.

Comment: Are you sure all your rhs_arr[net->nodes[x]->markov_parents[i]] strings are null terminated? your parent_var_names strings will not be.

Comment: So, if it's C++ you should be using `std::string` and not be trying to both manage and use resources. Either manage them (make `std::string`) or use them (use `std::string`), do not do both. It's error prone, leaky, and messy.

Comment: yea, theyre all null terminated. when the copy happens, parent_var_names has obvious un-terminated strings. i probably should have mentioned that

Comment: i want c and c++ compatibility, otherwise i would have used std::string a long time ago

Comment: is there any reason for int i(1) instead of int i(0) or int i = 0?

Comment: Did you know C++ and C are two very different languages, and mixing them usually is not a very good idea? Is there any good reason you are not using C++ in an idiomatic way? Also, the unnecessary/violating casts really are hurting readability and don't make too much sense at all.

Comment: jmgunn87: What for? Leave it as C then, but I don't understand why you'd do that.

Comment: Is parent_var_names pointing to NULL or is *parent_var_names pointing to NULL?

Comment: yes i(1) is needed. c==speed and yes i'm aware you shouldn't mix but the only mixing i am doing is by compiling as c++, dhould i compile as c?

Comment: *parent_var_names is pointing to NULL

Comment: If you write C code, compile as C. If you write C++ code, compile as C++. This is C code. Please drop the C == speed crap so you can get on with your life. C++ is just as fast, and often times faster. And it's easier. Who *cares* how fast it is if it doesn't work? Make it work, profile it, optimize it. Program C++ if you're programming C++. Make it work clean, then fast.

Comment: @jmgunn87: you've lost your C compatibility by writing `int i(1)`: C doesn't have constructor syntax. If you want your code to be compilable as C, you really need to test whether it is or not, by compiling it as C. If, for some odd reason, you also want it to compile as C++, then you need to also compile it as C++. For most purposes this is pointless, though, since it's easy to compile code as C then link it with C++. Header files used from both languages are the only place you normally *need* code that compiles as both.

Comment: "knowledge is deep understanding of how things work when taken apart"(Pearl 2009).Librarys and API's are great for use but not for learning. besides, c IS faster.

Comment: @steve, i'm aware. but i'm more interested in getting my code working right now and this code was inserted for test. please can i have some help with the issue rather than being educated on the syntax of c(which i already know very well).

Comment: does anyone have an idea on how to help???

Comment: @jmgunn87: have you had a look at the answers below the comments to see if any help out?

Comment: @jmgunn87, I wonder how well you know C if you don't realize that array indices begin at 0 and that you need to allocate space for a string plus the NULL terminator.

Comment: Okay, what you you mean?  Is it true that `parent_var_names == NULL`?  `*parent_var_names == parent_var_names[0] == NULL`?

Comment: @jmgunn87:  Sometimes it's faster and easier to just junk bad code and rewrite it properly than to fix the bad code.  This looks like one of those cases where `std::vector<std::string>` could save you a lot of time.

Comment: -1 for continued ignorance. C is not faster. C is a language. 
C++ is a language. Maybe you mean implementations too. That's ignorance. Wrong again there too, of course. Do you have any actual profiling results or are you just repeating old dumb dogma? Of course not. Just freakin write C++ and move on. If it's actually slow enough where you notice (hint: it isn't. If it were, you'd be in a position to actually know what you're saying, but you don't), then fix it.

Answer (score 3):

`int i(1)` in your `for` loop init should probably be `int i(0)`.

Otherwise you're never setting `parent_var_names[0]` to anything other than the `0` that `calloc()` initializes it to.

Just for completeness (since this is mentioned a couple times in the comments), you're not taking into account the '\0' terminator for the strings you're copying. Since you're not copying the terminator in your `strncpy()` calls, you're not overflowing the buffers allocated, but your results aren't properly-terminated strings.  It's possible that this is your intent, but that would be unusual. If it is intended, throw a comment in there...

Answer (score 3):

Placing guard bytes (i.e. 0xFDFDFDFD) around an allocated region of memory is a feature of the (Microsoft) debug heap. Seeing that you encounter this value either means you are overwriting memory somewhere, or you are looking at the value of `parent_var_names[0]` without actually writing anything in there (i.e. take a close look at the value you initialize your loop variable `i`with).

Furthermore, your code could be simplified to:

```
#include <string>
/* ... */

int ii = 0;
int parent_count = net->nodes[x]->num_parents;
char** parent_var_names = calloc(parent_count, sizeof(char*));

for(; ii < parent_count; ++ii)
{
    parent_var_names[ii] = strdup(rhs_arr[net->nodes[x]->markov_parents[ii]]);
}
```

Also make sure your markov_parents are definitely zero-terminated. Btw., in response to your comment that you want "C and C++ compatibility": Your code is not valid C code, so ...

Answer (score 1):

If your `parent_var_names` aren't NULL terminated it's probably because you are using `strlen` when you allocate space for the strings. This fails to create space for the string **and** the NULL terminator. Try `strlen()+1` instead.

You should probably be using std::string anyway...

Comment: ok, i took a break and had a look again with fresh eyes. the int i(1) was the obvious error. I copy and pasted further up the file for that loop(now i know why thats a no-no!). sometimes when youve been staring at the screen for hours you just can't see whats blatantly obvious staring you in the face. cheers anyway all.

Comment: how do i rate people on here?

Comment: oh and blastfurnace.. on the PM you sent me.. I take it mistakes are never made by you? I spose you probably dont work hard enough to have had that happen to you. learn some humility. If i didnt know arrays in most programming languages are 0-indexed i dont think i'd be getting much done and believe me i do.

Comment: It was nothing personal. You just seemed to be getting upset with Steve Jessop and others that were offering advice on the code you posted. That the code had a fairly simple mistake was at odds with your assertion of expertise with C. I know we all make mistakes and I'm glad you found an answer to your problem. You should accept either Jim Brissom's or Michael Burr's answer if they were helpful. Have a nice day.